# java regex to remove numbers including ,

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

String :

```
"75,000", "is", "95%", "or", "95/100" "of", "monthly", "income"
```

o/p :

```
"is","%, "or", "/", "of", "monthly", "income"
```

i am trying below : In for loop

```
        if (String.matches("[\\d]*[.,]*[\\d%]"))
                {   
                    String = String.replaceAll("[\\d]*[.,]*[\\d%]","");
                    String.previous();
                    String.set(token);
                    String.remove();
                    String.next();
                }
```

but it is not picking up numbers at all.

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Does that code even compile?

Comment: It seems wrong in the way i posted it (string is string builder). I just wanted to give an overview of logic i am implementing.

Comment: Is it a single string with embedded quotes, or an array or list? Please show input and expected output - but edit your question carefully - be precise so we can be confident of what you want. Right now it all looks a little weird

Comment: Apologies for putting the question in unstructured way.

It is a array list.

Comment: What does "o/p" mean? And is it simply that you want to remove all digits from all strings in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(\\d+[,/%]?\\d*)
```

Matches:
 75,000 
 95% 
 95/100

or

```
"(\\d+,\\d+)|\\d+"
```

MAtches:
  75,000
  95
  100
  (digit),(digit) or digit

This pattern:

```
[^\\d,]+  or eventually [^\\d,\\"]+
```

Matches:
  is
  %
  or
  /
  of
  monthly
  income

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression :

```
"\\d*[.,]?\\d+%?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"\\d*[.,]?\\d+%"
```

This will match a number with an optional `,` or `.` and a `%` at the end.
If you want to match numbers, which can end in a `%` or not, just add a `?` at the end.

Comment: You're first line is not correct. In java, `\d` needs to be escaped, even in a character class.

Comment: "\\d*[.,]?\\d+%"

this regex is not picking "75,000"

Comment: @RohitJain Okay, I'll edit that out. Thanks for the correction.